# How can this be right?

Tags: wordplay

I'm a typical human being in a real place, on this planet Earth, right about now, in a developed country, in an everyday situation.

I realise that for me, right is simultaneously left, right, and wrong.

Where am I?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has had a go at this. Not a tricky one by the standards of this community to be sure - my son and I came up with it when he was about 6, walking to school (not a spoiler or a clue!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feels like a problem that probably has multiple decent solutions, but how about this? You are

> in the United Kingdom, driving a car.

Right is left:

> It is right to drive on the left.

Right is right:

> Everything is equal to itself.

Right is wrong:

> It is wrong to drive on the right.

Comment: Realize vs. Realise haha

Comment: @aznbanana9 UK and US, divided by a common language...

Answer (score 1):

Where am I?

> I'm a dissident writer and reporter, fighting for the rights of
>  freedom and highlighting the excesses and abuses of the leadership in
>  my country.  I'm in a country where freedom is restricted, and abuses are common. (Note: I had originally included a few choice country
>  selections, but you get the general idea..)

Left

> I'm exercising my rights in a liberal, somewhat left leaning way.

Right

> And what's right is right.  Let justice and freedom prevail.

Wrong

> But the consequences of standing up for what I believe in have made me
>  a traitor in my own country.

Comment: "I'm a typical human being in a real place, on this planet Earth, right about now, in a developed country, in an everyday situation." I don't feel that this matches your answer.

Comment: Neat answer, and correct if one allows subjective judgements - which weren't outlawed in the question. I gave the answer tick to the solution which was 1/mine and 2/ is objectively correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I am  the captain of a ship standing at the front of the boat facing my crew.

Right

> I cry out "Turn to starboard".
>  Starboard is the [right-hand-side of a ship facing forwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_and_starboard)

Is simultaneously left

> Starboard is to my left

Right

> It is to my crew's right

Wrong

> Just realised that we will crash into the docks!! HELP!

Comment: Ingenious, correct in its own terms, but hopefully not an everyday situation! Not on my ship at least.